# if click default button address should be default

Tags: codeigniter

One user multiple shipping address how to make it as default,if click the make as default button,that address should be default and remaining all address shown the make as default button in a particular address box,except default address box.

**view page**

```
<?php foreach ($buyer_Address as $row) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default add_min_height">
            <div class="panel-heading">Default:</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="de" id="de" value="<?php echo $row->b_id; ?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <address><?php echo $row->b_fullname; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $row->b_street_address; ?>,<?php echo $row->b_locality ?>,<br>
                    <?php echo $row->b_landmark; ?>,
                    <?php echo $row->b_city; ?>, <?php echo $row->b_state; ?>,<?php echo $row->b_pincode; ?>
                    India
                    Phone number: <?php echo $row->b_mobile_number; ?></address>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/buyereditaddress?id=<?php echo $row->b_id; ?>" >Edit</a> 
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/buyerdeleteaddress?id=<?php echo $row->b_id; ?> ">Delete</a>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                <?php if ($row->status == '0') { ?>
                    <button type="submit" style="color:#337ab7;background: none !important;border: none;" name="default" id="default">Make as deafault</button> 
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**controller**

```
 public function defaultAddress() {
        $id = $this->input->post('de');
        $this->BuyerProfile_Model->defaultAddress($id);
        redirect('welcome/buyeraddresses');
    }
```

**model**

```
 function defaultAddress($id) {

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query("UPDATE buyer_order_address SET status = '0' WHERE b_id = '$id'");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE buyer_order_address SET status = '1' WHERE b_id = '$id'");
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: personal opinion, but the php code written this way, it's horrible

Comment: anything wrong means suggest me ok, this is a learning and helping to each other...then how to write tell me waiting for ur reply @Leo

Comment: leaving the aesthetics of the code, let's talk about your problem .. could you clarify it more?

Comment: one user multiple shipping  address are there, every address default button is there,if click the default button,address should be default like amazon above i shown screen shot@Leo

Comment: ok, now I understand what you would do, the problem is that you can not make this step to set an address by default?

Comment: i dnt no how to make address as default now help me @Leo

Comment: you can click "Create as default" to call a function to create a query that updates the status (ex: address_status) of that address.
ex: 0 = not default
1 = default

Comment: okay same thing i done..mine problem is query once check and modify if possible @Leo

Comment: what happened Leo sir your not replying @Leo

Comment: sorry, but now I have a personal commitment .. however, once you click the button, put all the status back to 0 and then change to one just the one you want, and so far we are. after this passage I did not understand what the other problem is .-.

Comment: thanks for your help(smart coder)@Leo